# How to use(create db, create table, query, etc) praeclarum sqlite-net?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, sqlite-net

I want to use sqlite-net available from this link https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net.

Unfortunately, the getting started documentation are not enough. It doesnt even mention how to create a database. I tried looking at the examples, unfortunately, the examples are broken(unable to compile, run time error etc).

The most practical tutorial i can find on the net is http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/

Unfortunately, sqlite-net doesnt fully support sqlite.org sqlite implementation, thus making the tutorial useless for praeclarum sqlite-net.

What is the equivalent method to do the same thing from the tutorial but in praeclarum sqlite-net?

From the tutorial

Create database(Here is where i stuck)

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.sqlite");
```

Connect to database

```
SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
m_dbConnection.Open();
```

Create table

```
string sql = "create table highscores (name varchar(20), score int)";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Fill table

```
string sql = "insert into highscores (name, score) values ('Me', 3000)";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
sql = "insert into highscores (name, score) values ('Myself', 6000)";
command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
sql = "insert into highscores (name, score) values ('And I', 9001)";
command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Query database

```
string sql = "select * from highscores order by score desc";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + reader["name"] + "\tScore: " + reader["score"]);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title. As it reads now, your question is a request to locate a tutorial, and that question is off-topic here. (Questions asking for links to off-site locations are inappropriate.) As it appears that's not what you're really asking, you should fix the title to more accurately reflect your question. If you don't, it will probably be closed rather soon.

Comment: Are you open to alternatives ? how about [using this](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) I'm using that in a project and it works great.

Comment: @Noctis While I do open to alternatives, the reason I want to learn praeclarum sqlite-net is because it is multiplatform(ios,android,windows phone). Thanks.

Comment: lol ... just realized you are using the tutorial I used months ago when looking into sqlite :). from a quick look at pareclarum, you'll have to create classes for your DB, and it will create the tables for you from them (which is kinda cool i think)

Comment: IMHO that tutorial is quickest quickstart tutorial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your Where you can use lambdas.  The classes are strongly typed.

Makes things a lot cleaner.

If you get into any amount of data caching, you'll end up wishing you had something like Microsoft's sync framework to use in Mono.  I'm really guessing by your post, that you are looking at using Xamarin.  Take a look at their SQLCipher component, if you are going to be caching data locally.

Also, if you do use SQLCipher via the component store.. it works in Android 2.3 on up.  So don't expect a fully backward compatible system even with the Support Library added to your project.

`var db = new SQLiteConnection("sqllite.db")`

`db.CreateTable<SyncRecord> ();`

`db.Insert (new SyncRecord () { SyncDate =  DateTime.UtcNow });`

`var query = db.Table<SyncRecord> ().Where( /* your lambda  to filter*/);`

Comment: Thanks. The syntax are totally different. Save a lot of my time.

Comment: Accepted. Could you help me on general SQL queries on my suggested answer? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a CreateTable method, I'm using a SQLiteConnection object, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, are you using SQLLiteNet?

Answer (score 2):

My suggested answer is based on @Slack-Shot response.

I try to convert the tutorial to be praeclarum sqlite syntax compatible for reference to other super noobs like me.

Create and/or connect to database

```
private string dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine
    (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location),
     "MyDatabase.sqlite");

using (var m_dbConnection = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath)) {}
```

Create table

```
public class highscore
{
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int score { get; set; }
}

using (var m_dbConnection = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
{
    m_dbConnection.CreateTable<highscore>();
}
```

Fill table

```
using (var m_dbConnection = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
{
    m_dbConnection.Insert(new highscore()
    {
        name = "Me",
        score = 9001
    });
    m_dbConnection.Insert(new highscore()
    {
        name = "Me",
        score = 3000
    });
    m_dbConnection.Insert(new highscore()
    {
        name = "Myself",
        score = 6000
    });
    m_dbConnection.Insert(new highscore()
    {
        name = "And I",
        score = 9001
    });
}
```

Query database

Assuming I have a simple SQL string like so:
"select * from highscores order by score desc"

How do I display it in this form:

```
for(int i = 0; i < totalDataQueried; i++)
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name[i] + "\tScore: " + score[i]);
```

Comment: first, read a short 3 min intro to [lambda expressions](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/298963/Understand-Lambda-Expressions-in-3-minutes). then, what do you need / want to query next?

Comment: var items = m_dbConnection.Table<highscore>().OrderByDescending( t => t.score);
That's a lambda expression that will order by descending.

Comment: Then, you can use something like.. 
foreach(highscore hs in items) 
Console.WriteLine("Name: "+hs.name+"\tScore:"+hs.score);