# How to get data from database? SQLite on Winrt

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, sqlite-net

I got ready-to-use .db database in my project folder with fields "city","area" and added data.

So how to get info from the database where city == some value?

I use C#, sqlite-net and SQLite.

Comment: what exactly are you looking out for connection to sqlite or just sql code to get the required data? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Nimesh
I didn't try anything cuz all articles show how to create NEW database, but I need to get data from existing .db file.
I'm looking for sqlite code(connection, etc), not query(I know query).

Comment: Did you check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851213/how-to-usecreate-db-create-table-query-etc-praeclarum-sqlite-net?rq=1)?

Comment: @Nimesh Yes. I've seen code like this before. And I got some questions. How to get data from existing database and table? They show how to create table and get data from it.

Comment: From that article, second code block is for connecting the existing database and last code block is for fetching the data using select statement. Combining these two, you should be able to connect to your database and fetch the required data.

Comment: @Nimesh if u're talking about the code in the question, then the last code doesn't work cuz SQLiteDataReader class doesn't exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let say you have the following single table database that looks like this :

[image: DataBase schema]

- add the database ".db" file to your project, i choose to put it in a **Data Folder** to keep the project structured,
- set the build action of the database file to content so it will be copied to the **AppX** file when you compile,

[image: Build action]
 - Now, the "*.db*" file needs to be copied to the **Local** (or **Roaming**) folder based on your need and on the size of the database, add the following method to the *App.xaml.cs* file

```
    private async Task CopyDatabase()
        {
            bool isDatabaseExisting = false;
            try
            {
                var s = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
                StorageFile storageFile 
                    = await     ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("DataBase.db");
                isDatabaseExisting = true;                
            }
            catch
            {
                isDatabaseExisting = false;
            }
            if (!isDatabaseExisting)
            {
                StorageFile databaseFile = await 
                    Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Data\DataBase.db");
                await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);                
            }
        }
```

the above code will copy the database to the **Local folder** from the InstalledLocation (**Appx**),

- call this methods in the `OnLaunched` method:
  [image]
- In order for you to execute Sql queries on the database, there are several ways one of them is by using [SQLitePCL](https://sqlitepcl.codeplex.com/documentation) library, so add it to your project using [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCL/3.8.2) :

> Install-Package SQLitePCL

- add as well a reference to *SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1)* using that [Vs extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1d04f82f-2fe9-4727-a2f9-a2db127ddc9a)
- add the data model: for each table in the database create a class that will hold the same structure, here we have only one table '`Data`':

  ```
   public class Data
    {
      public long Id { get; set; }
      public String City { get; set; }
      public String Area { get; set; }
    }
  ```
- add a class that will hold all the data's interaction logic, and add all the needed operations with the database using `Sqlite.netPcl` lib:

  ```
   public class DataService
   {
  private readonly SQLiteConnection _connection;
  public DataService()
  {
      _connection = new SQLiteConnection("DataBase.db");
  }

  public async Task<List<Data>> GetAllCities()
  {
      var cities = new List<Data>();
      using (var statement = _connection.Prepare("SELECT * FROM Data"))
      {
          while (statement.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
          {
              cities.Add(new Data()
              {
                  Id = (long)statement[0],
                  City = (string)statement[1],
                  Area = (string)statement[2]                      
              });
          }
      }
      return cities;
  }
  ```

  }

there are no need here for the method to be `async` but you may consider that in advanced scenarios,

- finally to get the data simply call the `GetAllCities` method:

  ```
    public async void MainPage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   {
      var dataService=new DataService();
      ListV.ItemsSource = await dataService.GetAllCities();

  }
  ```

the Xaml :

```
    <ListView x:Name="ListV" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding City}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Area}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Oh dude! Thanks a lot! You explained why we need class for table.
Thanks again!